# Explaining ArcGIS Raster to Polygon output?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, reclassify

I want create a new shapefile with selected fields found in a raster which depicts landcover.

I first attempted to run Raster To Polygon.  However, some class names no longer appear, as shown here:

[image]

I need help understanding what's going on and the best way to extract ALL the class names into a shapefile.  I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2 and selecting by "CLASS_NAME", Simplify. I have also attempted using "VALUE" and No_Simplify, but get the same results. I added the raster data if that helps

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you're using ArcGIS, but which version?

Comment: Also, what parameters are you running the tool with?

Comment: @om_henners ArcMap 10.2.2  "CLASS_NAME", Simplify.  I have attempted the only other options using "VALUE" and No_Simplify, but get the same results.  I added the raster data if that helps.

Comment: Don't forget that there is an **edit** button that you can use to revise your question with extra details that are requested via comments.  Our [Tour] is well worth taking.

Comment: The RAT (Raster attribute table) has one entry per pixel value (255 for 8bit raster) where one value describes lots of pixels which may or may not be disjoint, the polygons have one row per polygon and are definitely disjoint, hence the difference in record count. I don't know why your polygon gridcode != raster Value, if it's important join your polygons to your RAT by attribute and field calculate GRIDCODE = CDL_2014.VALUE. If your raster does not have an instance of CLASS_NAME, like no 'Almonds' are being grown in this area, there's still an entry in the table but no polygon can exist.

Comment: I can't see the entirety of your raster attribute table, but sometimes there is a COUNT field that tells you how many pixels in each class there are. Any classes with zero pixels wouldn't show up in the vectors because there's nothing to convert. If there is no count you could possibly use Summary Statistics to get one. As Michael mentions, the first step is to verify those pixel values/classes actually occur in the raster and not just the attribute table. I, too, am confused by the lack of GRIDCODE/value correlation.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure all your classes are represented in your feature class. They will be further down in the attribute table. You have more than 200.000 features.

As Michael said, when you convert a raster into a Polygon, pixels of the same class, which are not directly connected will be represented in a different class.

Try to dissolve you new feature class (data management tools, generalize, dissolve). Use Class_name as dissolve field.
This should reduce the numbers of features to the number of classes you had in your raster table. Features will be represented as multi polygons.

Comment: I did run Dissolve, and it did reduce the number of features as you described.  However, there are just 43 unique features (CLASS_NAME) after using Dissolve, whereas the original landcover .tif (CDL_2014) has 132.

Comment: How are you sure all classes are represented? It appears the asker has sorted both attribute tables on class name, and if that is the case it is clear there are several missing values between the three on the right as compared to the list on the left. And did you mean 'different feature' in your second paragraph? They should have the same *class* attributes but would be different *features* (or rows/records). @JackBauer When you dissolved, did you allow or not allow multipart features? If you allowed, then you would basically have one multipart feature per class rather than unique features.